# Nan issue in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, internet-explorer-11

I have the following javascript -

```
datefrom = new Date(event.min);

                           if (datefrom != 'Invalid Date') {

                               var day = datefrom.getDate();
                               var month = datefrom.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                               var year = datefrom.getFullYear();
                               var hour = datefrom.getHours();
                               var min = datefrom.getMinutes();

                               if (day < 10)
                                   day = "0" + day;
                               if (month < 10)
                                   month = "0" + month;
                               if (hour < 10)
                                   hour = "0" + hour;
                               if (min < 10)
                                   min = "0" + min;

                               datefrom = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min;


                               $("#DateBox1").val(datefrom);
                           }
                           else {
                               alert('IM HERE!!!');
                               $("#DateBox2").val(originalFrom);
                           }
```

When using the application in Chrome and FireFox I can successfully get into the `else` statement and alert "!M HERE!!!" no bother, as datefrom is an invalid date.

However IE states that date from is `NaN` and for some reason I can't get into the else statement.

I have put alrets within the if statement to see where I am when running and for some reason I just can't get into the else and set the correct value in IE. Why is this happening???

Comment: try parseInt() method

Comment: Are you able to reproduce issue on jsFiddle? What is value of `event.min`?

Comment: The return value of `new Date(event.min)` will never be `'Invalid Date'` (see [EMCA-262 section 15.9.3.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1)) unless *event.min* is a string and you have replaced the *Date.parse* method. The value returned by `new Date()` will either be a Date object or `NaN`.

Comment: I guess you want to check it's whether a `Date`, try this
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(datefrom) == "[object Date]") {
...
} else { alert('IM HERE'); }

Comment: @RobG Then check `Object.is()` ES6, but you can get the code here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

`Object.is(NaN, 0/0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know what the input value is, but in general you need to be aware that there are a number of known cross-browser quirks when working with the built-in `Date` object. A string that is successfully parsed as a date in one browser may not be seen as valid in another.

Secondly, testing for `"Invalid Date"` is probably not the best way to determine whether the date is valid. I would suggest that `if(isNaN(datefrom.getDate()))` is probably going to be a better test.

Finally, if you're parsing date strings, you might want to consider using one of the third-party libraries that are available for making dates easier to work with in JS. Look up either [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). These libraries will give you better cross-browser compatibility, and also additional features that aren't in the standard Date object.

Comment: The only quirk that most will encounter in different implementations is the parsing of strings. That likely stems from *Date.parse* being completely implementation dependent until ES5, which specifies a version of IS) 8601. However, that format is not supported by some browsers in use and anything other than that one format is still implementation dependent. There is another quirk related to IE and the expression `new Date(date)` where *date* is a date object with a year from 10 to 99, but that is avoided by using `new Date(+date)` and is extremely unlikely to be encountered anyway.

Comment: @RobG: The *different implementations in string parsing* is what I was referring to, since that seems to be where the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below line to check the valid date instead of `datefrom != 'Invalid Date'`

```
if(datefrom.getTime === "function" && isFinite(datefrom.getTime()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what `event.min` is, so we are left to speculate on what might be causing the error.

The Date constructor will return either a Date object or `NaN`, so the test `datefrom != 'Invalid Date'` should always be true as `new Date(...)` will never return the string 'Invalid Date' where the implementation complies with any version of ECMAScript.

If the result is `NaN`, it means that the constructor was unable to create a valid date object from whatever was passed to it according to the rules in [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), which might mean that it's a value that, when converted to a primitive:

1. Is a string that, when parsed, does not result in a valid date
2. Is a number that is greater than 8.64e15 and so exceeds the allowed value for a time clip

In the first case, there are many strings that can be successfully parsed by some implementations but not by others. There are also strings that can be successfully parsed (i.e. result in a Date object) by two implementations  but result in different dates, e.g. 2014-03-24T20:20:00 will be treated (correctly) by Chrome as UTC but (incorrectly) as local by Firefox.